# MVC 3 Publish not publishing dlls from referenced project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, reference, publish

I have a project `Foo.BackOffice` . it has a reference to `Foo.Repository` which I have NHibernate dlls.

When i publish `Foo.BackOffice` to IIS. It doesnt publish the dlls which are in Foo.Repository, NHibernate DLLs. But it does publish the `Foo.Repository.dll`.

How can I publish the dll's that Foo.Repository has as reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690515/vs-2010-publish-web-deployment-not-copying-child-dependency-project-assemblies) issue:

> The behavior you're seeing is currently by-design. The compiler only
>   copies indirect references for which it can find a compile-time
>   dependency. In this case, it determines that your Web project doesn't
>   have a compile time dependency on Project B. Direct dependencies will
>   always be copied.

You only have direct dependency on `Foo.Repository` not on Nhibernate.

So just reference the NHibernate dlls in your web project and they will copied during publish.

Comment: that s by design ? interesting decision. so now i have to include same references in all the projects? do u think that s a good design?

Comment: You just need to include them in your web projects if you want them to get published. Or you copy them manually after publish...

Comment: This design sucks! I have dependencies in layer further down and now I have to include them all in my web layer for publishing to work. Rubbish!